# In what sense do complex functions have norms?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can someone please correct my misunderstanding about bound and norms?

By Liouville Theorem, a complex function is bounded if and only if it is a constant function.

By this logic wouldn't all complex functions with finite norm (bounded) be constant functions?

Comment: The theorem is for *entire* functions.

Comment: An *entire* complex function is bounded if and only if it is constant. An arbitrary complex function can be bounded but not constant. Also, "finite norm $\iff$ bounded" only applies to one type of norm (the $L^{\infty}$ norm). Other norms such as the $L^p$ norms can be finite for unbounded functions.

Comment: But for example, $H_2$ space is only defined for entire/holomorphic functions. @Bungo, so Liouville Theorem's "bounded" refers to the $L^\infty$ norm only?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the $H^2$ space, but a quick Wikipedia check shows that its elements are functions which are holomorphic on the unit disk, not necessarily on the entire complex plane. A non-constant entire function can certainly be bounded on the unit disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misstated Liouville's theorem. The crucial assumption is "analytic and bounded in the WHOLE PLANE". An analytic function is some other region, for example in the unit disk, can be bounded, without being a constant, and you may consider various norms of such functions.

But even for analytic functions in the plane one can introduce various norms.
For example
$$\| f\|=\sup_z|e^{-|z|^2}f(z)|$$
This is a norm. Function does not have to be bounded to have this norm finite.